# Error while passing table as a parameter to the stored procedure in Entity Frame Work

Tags: stored-procedures, user-defined-types

Actual  I was working on stored procedure by passing a table as a parameter using EntityFrameworkExtras package

below is the code 
Step 1: Created user defined type in SQL SERVER

```
                   CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UserDefineType] AS TABLE(
                   [ID] [int] NULL,
                   [Value] [int] NULL
               )
```

Step 2: Created stored procedure and use above defined type in step 1 as parameter of stored procedure

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestStoredProcedure]
    (@name varchar(100)
    ,@description varchar(500)
    ,@udt UserDefineType READONLY
   )
AS
  BEGIN
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
         (
            [ID] , [Value]
          )
          SELECT ID,Value          
           FROM @udt
    END
```

Step 3: Created class for User Defined Type

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents User Defined Type for database
    /// </summary>
       [UserDefinedTableType("UserDefinedType")]
        public class UserDefinedType
      {
       [UserDefinedTableTypeColumn(1)]
       public int ID { get; set; }
       [UserDefinedTableTypeColumn(2)]
        public int Value { get; set; }
      }
```

Step 4: Created class for User Defined Type

```
         public class TestStoredProcedure    
         {
         [StoredProcedureParameter(SqlDbType.NVarChar, ParameterName="name")]
          public string Name { get; set; }


    [StoredProcedureParameter(SqlDbType.NVarChar,ParameterName="description")]
          public string Description { get; set; }    

       [StoredProcedureParameter(SqlDbType.Udt, ParameterName = "udt")]
           public List<UserDefinedType> UserDefinedType { get; set; }
         }
```

But while calling that procedure I am getting error like

(Column, parameter, or variable @udt. : Cannot find data type UserDefinedType.) 
[image]